# Rolling back a "deleted" question

Tags: discussion, rollbacks

I've seen a few questions that are already answered, but an OP deleted the whole content and replaced it with dots or random letters (............. or fjsdifjsdifskd).
This is one of those questions (I rolled it back): [PHP - cURL with a website like this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8376207/php-curl-with-website-like-this)

Should I rollback such a question, report to moderator or ignore it?

Comment: Roll back, flag if the OP repeats the deletion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the OP defaced the question, rollback - no need to involve moderators at this time, as it could have been an honest mistake.

In the eventuality that the OP does this again, they have shown that this was not a mistake - rollback again and flag.

Comment: You didn't get me. Question exists, but it's content is replaced with dots or random letters. Here's one of those that I've rolled back: [click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8376207/php-curl-with-website-like-this)

Comment: @NikolaK. - Ahh. You really should have posted that in your question to make it all clear.